# Is it possible to use a comparator to delete items from a list?

Tags: c#

I have a POCO like this:

```
class Poco{
    int first;
    int last;
    int category;
}
```

and a list

```
List<Poco> pocoList;
```

I need to remove items from the list where they overlap with an item with a specified category, overlap being defined as:

```
if (a.category!=category && (a.first >= b.first && a.first <= b.last) || (a.last >= b.first && a.last <= b.last)){
  // delete item a 
}
```

Two overlapping items will never have the same category.  Last is always greater than first.  First and last define a range.  It is possible that there is more than one overlap.

The list is sorted such that List[n].start < List[n+1].start is always true.

For example, given a category of 10, I need to delete all items that do not have a category of 10 and where any part of the range of that item overlaps with the range of an item with category 10.

My current implementation is crude and in profiling my app, I can see that >65% of the entire time of the processing branch where it's used is spent in this loop, not surprisingly.

```
for (int i=object.pojoList.Count-1;i>=0;i--){
    for (int j=object.pocoList.Count-1;j>=0;j--){
        if (pocoList[i].overlaps(pocoList[j],category){
            pocoList.RemoveAt(j);
        }            
    }
}
```

I feel that there must be a way to delete items using a comparator or LINQ but I can't figure it out.

Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: Does the code have typos? `a.first >= b.first || a.first <= b.last` will be true if `b.first <= b.last`, which practically means always.

Comment: Also shouldn't it be `i>=0` and `j>=0`? Also do you want your `overlaps` relation to be symmetrical, as at the moment it isn't. (`a overlaps b` doesn't necessarily imply `b overlaps a`.)

Comment: @Jon Yes, typos,  fixed.  Should be if any part of a overlaps any part of b.

Comment: @Rawling  I used pseudo code to simplify and I wrote the definition of "overlaps" as an if in an attempt to clarify my description.  I believe it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input list is in `start` order, you can try something like

```
List<Poco> potentialOverlaps = new List<Poco>();
for (int i = 0; i < pocoList.Count; i++)
{
    var currentPoco = pocoList[i];

    // Clear out overlaps that end before this poco starts.
    potentialOverlaps.RemoveAll(p => p.last < currentPoco.first);

    if (currentPoco.category == category)
    {
        potentialOverlaps.Add(currentPoco);
    }
    else if (potentialOverlapsCount > 0)
    {
        pocoList.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

The result might not be the same as what your code gives, but it should match your described behaviour.

It keeps track of the `Poco` in your selected category that "haven't yet ended"; if it comes across an out-of-category `Poco` and there are any that "haven't yet ended", it must overlap with one of them so can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your class implement IComparer.

You have to implement the method Compare(Object, Object) in a way that it returns 1, 0 or -1 for greater, equal or less respectively.

Source for a good examaple: [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727)

You could set on one list the delimiters of the other. Then, when sorting using the above method, if the value overlaps the range of the delimiters, you remove it instead.